# AngularJS: error en Array, Servicio de JSON

Tags: angularjs

Quiero sacar la primera registro del array pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo :

```
servicioMiClaro.obtenerDirecciones().then(function (response) {
           $scope.listadoProductoServicios  = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
        });

console.log( $scope.listadoProductoServicios.listadoProductoServicios[0].afiliado);}
```

Comment: En lugar de  `$scope.listadoProductoServicios.listadoProductoServicios[0].afiliado` no será `$scope.listadoProductoServicios[0].afiliado`? Además estás poniendo el `console.log` fuera del `then` y estás tratando de acceder a los valores antes de obtenerlos.

Answer (score 1):

Estás accediendo bien al primer registro del array.

```
$scope.listadoProductoServicios.listadoProductoServicios[0].afiliado
```

Pero el `console.log()` lo estás poniendo fuera de donde asignas los valores. Angular está basado en Javascript, por lo tanto es asíncrono, o sea que realiza la búsqueda `servicioMiClaro.obtenerDirecciones()` al mismo tiempo que imprime el `console.log`.

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
servicioMiClaro.obtenerDirecciones().then(function (response) { 
  $scope.listadoProductoServicios  = response.data;
  console.log(response.data);
  console.log($scope.listadoProductoServicios.listadoProductoServicios[0].afiliado);
}, function (error) {
   $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' +error.message;
});
```